How to useReducer with a random state?
I am making a game that has a random state, its a Nextjs/React app, and I'm trying to get generate a random state once the component loads through useEffect, but its being called twice somehow.
I initially, had generateInitialGameState() inside the 2nd argument of useImmerReducer which is the default state, but because that method has math.random() in it I was getting hydration-errors
So, after some research, I read that I could use useEffect() and essentially wait for the component to mount, and once that happens generate my initial state with random values then.
But the problem I'm facing now is, console.log('hello', initialState) will appear twice in console, and initialState will be different values.
I tried adding that if statement to stop it, but it doesn't work and I'm not sure how to go forward.
Here is my GameProvider
export const GameProvider = (props: Props) => {
  // Initialize with a placeholder state, to fix hydration errors that are caused by the randomness of the game
  const [state, dispatch] = useImmerReducer(gameReducer, placeholderGameState)

  // Wait till the component is mounted, before generating the initial game state
  useEffect(() => {
    if (state === placeholderGameState) {
      const initialState = generateInitialGameState()
      dispatch({ type: 'INITIALIZE_GAME', payload: initialState })
      console.log('hello', initialState)
    }
  }, [])

  return <GameContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>{props.children}</GameContext.Provider>
}

Here is the page.tsx code that calls the Provider
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <GameProvider>
      <div className='flex flex-col h-full'>
        <GameInfo />
        <Piano />
      </div>
    </GameProvider>
  )
}

